# Xcode doesn't generate headers for Swift code inside referenced folder

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Xcode auto generates a `MyModule-swift.h` so my ObjC code can reference Swift classes.

When I tried to use folder references instead of groups on Xcode the generated file doesn't have any mention to Swift classes and methods.

Is this the expected behavior? Shouldn't I be using folder reference to hold code?

Comment: This happened to me as well. Using git submodules and having to re-add new files in third party library was getting on my nerves. Unfortunately swift files inside referenced folders aren't being exposed to Objc at all